# Fermi Surface Contour Plot on the Brillouin zone

Tags: plotting

I have plotted ContourPlot3D of fermi surface

```
e2[kx_, ky_, kz_] = 
 1/3 (2 (Cos[Sqrt[3] kx] + 2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[(3 ky)/2]) Cos[
      3 kz] + Sqrt[
    9 Abs[E^(-(1/2) I (Sqrt[3] kx - ky)) + E^(-I ky) + E^(
        1/2 I (Sqrt[3] kx + ky))]^2 + (3 + 
       4 (-Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] + Cos[(3 ky)/2]) Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/
         2] Sin[3 kz])^2])
ContourPlot3D[e2[kx, ky, kz] == 
  0, {kx, (-4 \[Pi])/(3 Sqrt[3] a), (4 \[Pi])/(
  3 Sqrt[3] a)}, {ky, (-2 \[Pi])/(3 a), (2 \[Pi])/(3 a)}, {kz, -\[Pi]/
  c, \[Pi]/c}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The Brillouin zone looks like the 3D hexagonal lattice
[image]

How can I show the Fermi surface on the the above Hexagonal lattice? (Parameters a=1 and c=3)

Comment: You can use this: ``p = ContourPlot3D[...]; r = \[Pi]/a; h = -\[Pi]/c; \[Phi] = 0;
hexP = CirclePoints[{r, \[Phi]}, 6];
hex = ConvexHullRegion[(Append[#, -h] & /@ hexP)~
    Join~(Append[#, h] & /@ hexP)];
Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], hex}], p]`` However, you have to adjust ``r``, ``h`` and ``\[Phi]`` because I don't know how exactly they relate to your parameters ``a``, ``b`` and ``c``.

Comment: @Domen I ran the code you sent with appropriate parameters, but its giving an error that "ConvexHullRegion is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive"

Comment: Can you provide us the appropriate parameters, please?

Comment: @Domen I have edited the post with parameters. I hope that should be enough. If you can show me that you are that you are able to make a 3D hexagon. I think that should answer my question.

Comment: I see it now, you are probably using an older version of Mathematica. Replace ``ConvexHullRegion`` with ``ConvexHullMesh`` in my code.

Comment: @Domen awesome. I get a hexagon. You can post it as an answer. Also in the answer, can you describe what are r, h and $\phi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate hexagonal prism, you can `CirclePoints[r, \[Phi]}, 6]` together with `ConvexHullMesh[]`. This prism is defined by the radius $r$, height $h$, and it is rotated around the $z$-axis by the angle $\phi$.

```
a = 1;
c = 3;
p = ContourPlot3D[
   e2[kx, ky, kz] == 
    0, {kx, (-4 \[Pi])/(3 Sqrt[3] a), (4 \[Pi])/(3 Sqrt[
        3] a)}, {ky, (-2 \[Pi])/(3 a), (2 \[Pi])/(3 a)}, {kz, -\[Pi]/
     c, \[Pi]/c}, AxesLabel -> Automatic];

r = (4 \[Pi])/(3 Sqrt[3] a);
h = \[Pi]/c;
\[Phi] = 0;
hexagon = CirclePoints[{r, \[Phi]}, 6];
prism = ConvexHullMesh[(Append[#, -h/2] & /@ hexagon)~Join~(Append[#, h/2] & /@ hexagon)];
Show[p, Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], prism}]]
```

You should appropriately change the parameters for the prism so that its dimensions match the Brillouin zone (I have forgotten my solid state physics, so I am not sure how exactly should the Fermi surface be positioned relative to the hexagonal lattice).

[image: Mathematica graphics]